# How do you convert a tabbed or comma separated .txt file to a .csv file?

Tags: csv, type-conversion

If you have a file with a .txt extension that is already separated by commas or tabs else. How do you convert it to a .csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Change the filename from aRandomName.**txt** to aRandomName.**cvs**.